# How to render nested ul list for ancestry tree view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ancestry, content-tag

I want to render a structure shown below using content_tag where the collection is the ancestry object.

```
  <ul>
    <li>
       <a>Fruits</a>
     <ul>
       <li>
         <a>Apple</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Orange</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a>Colours</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's the answer, community, please, edit and tweak this post if it's wrong.

Create a helper method like this

```
def nested_groups(groups)
   content_tag(:ul) do
      groups.map do |group, sub_groups|
         content_tag(:li, group.name +  nested_groups(sub_groups))
      end.join.html_safe
   end  
end
```

then, pass the ancestry object to the method in the view:

```
<%= nested_groups(@groups.arrange) %>
```

it will render the ul-list the right way.

Comment: it should be another .html_safe for the inner content_tag `content_tag(:li, (group.name +  nested_groups(sub_groups)).html_safe)`

Comment: What would the code look like if 'groups' were a JSON string? I'm trying to convert nested JSON to ul/li. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

The following code will produce a properly nested list. See [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists2) for example.

At first create a helper:

```
module AttributeHelper
  def nested_attributes(attributes)
    content_tag :ul do
        attributes.each do |attribute|
            concat(content_tag(:li, attribute.name))
            if attribute.has_children? 
                concat(nested_attributes(attribute.children))
            end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Then use the helper method in your view:

```
= nested_attributes(@attributes.roots)
```