# Rails - Comments w acts_as_nested_set - When Deleting a Dependent Record is Deleting Destroy Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-sets, acts-as-nested-set

I have the following Models:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :threads, :dependent => :destroy

class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy

 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
    acts_as_nested_set
```

The issue I'm having is when a user deletes a group, all kinds of comments are being broken or deleted. I took a look at the logs and this is what's happening:

```
Comment Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments".commentable_id = 101 AND "comments".commentable_type = 'Thread') ORDER BY comments.created_at DESC
AREL (0.9ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."lft" > 649 AND "comments"."rgt" < 650)
AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "lft" = ("lft" - 2) WHERE ("lft" > 650)
AREL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "rgt" = ("rgt" - 2) WHERE ("rgt" > 650)
AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 381)
AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."lft" > 645 AND "comments"."rgt" < 646)
AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "lft" = ("lft" - 2) WHERE ("lft" > 646)
AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "rgt" = ("rgt" - 2) WHERE ("rgt" > 646)
AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 380)
AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."lft" > 648 AND "comments"."rgt" < 651)
AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "lft" = ("lft" - 4) WHERE ("lft" > 651)
AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "rgt" = ("rgt" - 4) WHERE ("rgt" > 651)
AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 379)
AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."lft" > 644 AND "comments"."rgt" < 647)
AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "lft" = ("lft" - 4) WHERE ("lft" > 647)
AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "rgt" = ("rgt" - 4) WHERE ("rgt" > 647)
AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 378)
AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."lft" > 642 AND "comments"."rgt" < 643)
AREL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "lft" = ("lft" - 2) WHERE ("lft" > 643)
AREL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "rgt" = ("rgt" - 2) WHERE ("rgt" > 643)
AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 377)
AREL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."lft" > 641 AND "comments"."rgt" < 652)
AREL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "lft" = ("lft" - 12) WHERE ("lft" > 652)
AREL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "comments" SET "rgt" = ("rgt" - 12) WHERE ("rgt" > 652)
AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "comments" WHERE ("comments"."id" = 376)
AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "threads" WHERE ("threads"."id" = 101)
AREL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "groups" WHERE ("groups"."id" = 57)
```

Is this normal behavior for acts as nested? I would have expect just the DELETE FROM COMMENTS where Comment.id = XXXX. But instead all this is going on and comment records are breaking.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thank you

**UPDATE w What is being used to prevent deep nesting:**

```
  after_save :ensure_max_nestedset_level
  def ensure_max_nestedset_level
    if self.level > 2
      self.move_to_child_of(parent.parent)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Delete problem with awesome_nested_set. May be you can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976085/deletion-of-a-parent-node-but-not-the-children-with-awesome-nested-set

Answer (score 3):

This should not be breaking records. When you delete a node, the tree has to be pruned. [The comments in `acts_as_nested_set`](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_nested_set/blob/master/lib/active_record/acts/nested_set.rb#L64-66) say that

> "both adding and removing an entry require a full table write."

The code in [this `before destroy` method in `acts_as_nested_set`](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_nested_set/blob/master/lib/active_record/acts/nested_set.rb#L197-206) is attempting reorganize the table when you delete the `Comment` records, and is normal behavior.

Comment: What Rails gem should I be using? Maybe that's the issue? gem XXX ?

Comment: Perhaps. I'd look at [`awesome_nested_set`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set). Collective Idea has some great gems. It has been a while since it's been updated, though, so YMMV. See also [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308787/using-rails-polymorphism-for-nested-comments/4308919#4308919).

Comment: nice reference post, perfectly helpful.

Comment: I see from another question you're trying out `awesome_nested_set`. [`nested_set`](https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set) also appears to be Rails 3 ready, if you want to try another (it's forked from awesome_nested_set as well, but is a gem).

Comment: Another interesting gem to try, which doesn't use the nested set model, but appears to be pretty fast (according to [reports](http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/dvlxa/rails_3_compatible_ancestry_122_gem_released/c13ajrr)): [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

Comment: Also, since we've turned this into a discussion thread :P you may even want to consider trying out a [document-oriented database](http://www.mongodb.org/), and store your threaded discussion inline.

Comment: "I see from another question you're trying out awesome_nested_set" Right, as covered in my answer above, which explained (first) that this is normal behavior.

Comment: how can I QA that when deleting nested items, it's not going to break other non-related items which is what was happening?

Comment: Also, I want to prevent nesting going to deep, so I added this in my model, can that be the problem ? (Q UPDATED)

Comment: (1) I would add tests to your test suite that builds a few nested items, deletes a particular entry, and then checks to see if the rest of the entries are broken or not. (2) Which gem is this with? `acts_as_nested_set` doesn't have this method as far as I can tell. However, `awesome_nested_set` and friends recalculate the tree when you call that method, so I would *think* that it should be safe, if perhaps a bit slow (a better solution may be to check *before* save if the nesting will be too deep; currently you're calculating twice if the level is `>` 2).

Comment: Here is a list of all similar gems and their recent activity: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Nesting

Answer (score 2):

Well it's apparently trying to maintain the hierarchy when deleting nodes, a common problem in SQL.

Which library are you using? Awesome Nested Set? Why it would result in broken records I'm not sure.

You can read more about the nested set approach here:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

See the "Nested Set Model" section, and the "Deleted Nodes" sub-section below for why deletions are managed the way they are.

So the delete statements would be normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely, but never impossible, that the gem you use is unable to delete items and keep the nestedness correct. So imho it is related to something you are doing. 
It might also be related to the polymorphic relation.

Did you test with the `ensure_max_nestedset_level` removed? Does it work then?
Does it work when you delete a single comment? Delete a parent-comment? (with nested elements under it).
Does it only fail when you delete a group/thread?

Answer (score 1):

Simple `acts_as_nested_set` creates a tree for all records in the comments table. I guess you should create one comment tree per thread. E.g. 
`acts_as_nested_set :parent_column => :parent_id, :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]`.

Notice also that by default associations created by `acts_as_nested_set` have `:dependent` set to `:delete_all`. So make sure that `:parent_id` is set correctly.

With above modifications when deleting a group, only comments which belong to the group (via threads) should be deleted.

BTW I use [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) recommended at [ruby-toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_nesting.html).