# Deletion of a parent node but not the children with awesome_nested_set?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Deletion of a parent node but not the children.

The child nodes should all be moved up to the level of the deleted parent.

How can I handle this scenario with awesome_nested_set plug in ?

**EDIT**

Before child deleted

Id , Title, lft, rgt, parent_id

1, root, 7, 12, nil

2, child, 8, 11, 1

3, sub child, 9, 10, 2

After deleted 2 record

Id , Title, lft, rgt, parent_id

1, root, 7, 12, nil

3, sub child, 9, 10, 1

I want to move sub child to immediate parent of deleted object. Is this a proper result ? Or lft and rgt should be change after delete ?

Comment: What if to update level manually decrementing it? UPD: decrementing in destroy action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Controller

```
  @node = Node.find(params[:id])
  @node.delete_node_keep_sub_nodes
  @node.reload
  @node.destroy
```

### Model

```
  def delete_node_keep_sub_nodes
    if self.child?
      self.move_children_to_immediate_parent
    else
      self.move_children_to_root
    end
  end

  def move_children_to_immediate_parent
    node_immediate_children = self.children
    node_immediate_parent = self.parent
    node_immediate_children.each do |child|
      child.move_to_child_of(node_immediate_parent)
      node_immediate_parent.reload
    end
  end

  def move_children_to_root
    node_immediate_children = self.children
    node_immediate_children.each do |child|
      child.move_to_root
      child.reload
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of this:

- Find parent of deleted node
- Move all children to new parent

Example

```
@node = Node.find(params[:id])
@children = @node.children
@parent = @node.parent
@children.each{ |child| child.move_to_child_of @parent }
```

Comment: @flOOr Do I need to rebuild my tree again after doing this ? Or Do I need to reload @parent after this ?

Comment: @flOOr Can I delete a node later after updating all it's child ?

Comment: Yes, you can delete node after updating

Comment: @flOOr I have updated my question. With the code you have mentioned I am getting the result which I have shown in question.